# Where can I learn about the structure of pdf files?

Tags: file, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to learn about how pdf files are created, I couldn't find any good or official reference to the internal structure of pdf files, like:

```
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj
```

Where could I learn about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a section of Adobe's website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) which references things related to the PDF file format.

The last time I checked, the only available source for the content was [this ISO document](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51502). However, it seems Adobe has now released this document with the same technical content [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: Could this one be the same from http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf ?

Comment: @riviraz: It looks like it is. Last time I checked it was not freely available, but it seems that has changed.

Answer (score 1):

We have written a whole series of blog articles about how PDF files work. In particular

http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/?s=%22Make+your+own+PDF+file%22

and

http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/?s=Understanding+the+PDF+file+format

might be useful.